# Find foreign keys based on data

Tags: sql-server, entity-relationship, data-science

I am looking at a database which has almost no foreign keys defined.

Is there a tool that can perform some data analysis/heuristics and "guess" the relations based on data. I am looking for some kind of report, which can be used as a manual guide/checklist.

Comment: If the column names are not the same how could any kind of a tool make those assumptions? And if the column names are the same you don't need a tool.

Comment: The column names are inconsistent - and cannot always be guessed right. Some PKs are defined as just [Id], some other PKs are defined as [EntityId] (CourseId, StudentId) etc. 

I was thinking of some kind of data-based analyzer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem - Every Table had a Object_ID column... But had secondary IDs too.
All were of a wierd GUID-ish form.
I ended up writing a brute force scanner (using Dynamic sql from informtion_schema.columns)

Of course this approach relied on the values being globally unique... If you have a bunch of int identity cols and no way to connect the Tables then you are in a bit of trouble!

Perhaps there is a timestamp column or a DateTime defaulting to GetDate() - you could use this to identidy records in different tables that are created at approx the same time.

A lot depends on your schema...

Comment: +1 for mentioning about globally unique identifiers and DateTime defaults - we have DateTime defaults for almost all tables, so that should help a lot in that direction!